# Can a form submit to different pages based on field value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, textbox

I would like to create a text field box and a submit button where:

index.html: If user input in text box field "123" click submit will go or jump to john.html page.

AND

If user input "456" click submit will go to chris.html page.

Both above should only have 1 text box field and 1 submit button.

```
<form>
<input type="code" name="code" size="15"/>

<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what you can't to implement?

Comment: Atomic_alarm, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you:

Simple Solution using `if...else-if`

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/3ankxLmu/)</kbd>**

**HTML**

```
<form action="javascript:redirect();">
    <input id="textBox" type="text" name="code" size="15" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function redirect() {
    var textValue = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    if(textValue == 123)
    {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com/john.html";
    }
    else if(textValue == 456)
    {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com/chris.html";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: The textBox input should be of type "text" (html4) or "number" (html5).

Comment: @HasseBjörk Yes Correct. Actually copied from OP's code. Anyways Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a switch statement

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" value="">
<button onClick="goPlaces()">Click It</button>
```

JS

```
window.goPlaces = function(){
var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
switch(input){
    case '123':
        window.location.href = "www.locationOne.com";
        break;
    case '456':
        window.location.href = "www.locationTwo.com";
        break;
    default:
        alert("notify invalid input");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add action='name_of_your_html_file.php' and method='post'

now you need to implement a bit php and redirection with javascript to help it done.

```
if(count($_POST)>0){
   if($_POST['code'] === "123" ){
      echo "<script> window.location.href='john.html' </script>";
      exit();
   }else{
      echo "<script> window.location.href='chris.html' </script>";
      exit();

   }
}
```

Comment: This is PHP, not html/javascript...

Answer (score 0):

This is not nice, but it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send( frm ) {
    if ( frm.code.value == "123" )
        frm.action = "john.html";
    else if ( frm.code.value == "456" )
        frm.action = "chris.html";
    else
        return false;
    return true;
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return send(this);">
    <input type="text" name="code" size="15"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Edit:**
This code will redirect the browser to john.html if 123 is entered, or chris.html if 456 is entered. On all other occasions it will do nothing!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, take care the website need to have the same origine as the form action.

html

```
<form id="testForm" methode="POST" action="https://jsfiddle.net/">
    <input id="testInput" type="text" />
    <button id="testBtn">Go</button>
 </form>
```

js

```
function editprofilefunction() {
    document.getElementById("testBtn").onclick=function(){
        if(document.getElementById("testInput").value === '123')
        {
            document.getElementById("testForm").setAttribute("action", "https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/");
        }
    };
}
editprofilefunction()
```